# curl error on my wampserver that wanna connect to localbitcoins

Tags: php, api, curl, wamp

Hi i use wamp server and the vertion on apache:2.4.9 php:5.5.12
i try to use curl with this code:

```
<?php
function localbitcoins_query($path, array $req = Array()) {
   $key='MY_KEY';
   $secret='MY_SECRET';
   $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
   $nonce = $mt[1].substr($mt[0], 2, 6);
   if ($req) {
      $get=httpbuildquery($req);
      $path=$path.'?'.$get;
   }
   $postdata=$nonce.$key.$path;
   $sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $postdata, $secret));
   $headers = array(
      'Apiauth-Signature:'.$sign,
      'Apiauth-Key:'.$key,
      'Apiauth-Nonce:'.$nonce
   );
   $ch = null;
   $ch = curl_init('https://localbitcoins.com'.$path);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curlerror($ch));
   $dec = json_decode($res, true);
   if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data: '.$res);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $dec;
}

$getinfo = array();
$devise = "EUR";
$url = "/buy-bitcoins-online/".$devise."/western-union/.json";

$getinfo = localbitcoins_query($url);   
echo "<pre>"; print_r($getinfo); echo "</pre>";
```

to connect to localbitcoins and get a error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curlerror() in C:\wamp\www\localbit\index.php on line 25
```

i think it is my wamp server but dont know 
i tried with more other codes but get no result of it now i got this error!

someone here who knows how curl works and tell me what i do wrong sorry if this quistion is asked before cuz i searsh on it and find nothing that can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, the correct function name is `curl_error`

Also make sure you have loaded the php-curl extension for wamp.

Comment: @danieldehlin If this answer has helped you to solve your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it and also give it an up-vote.